# Вложенность массивов в объекты

Tags: javascript

Код:

```
var Wire = {
    startx:0,
    starty:0,
}
var Knot = {
    id:0,
    x:0,
    y:0,
    Wires:[],
}
var Room = {
    x:0,
    y:0,
    width:0,
    height:0,
    Knots:[],
}
var facility = {
    width:0,
    height:0,
    x:0,
    y:0,
    Rooms:[],
}
var f = facility;
```

При обращении типа

```
f.Rooms[i].Knots.push(k);
```

Выдает ошибку:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Именно при обращении к `Knots`
Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Вы уверены что в массиве `Rooms` есть элемент с индексом `i`?

Comment: Каким образом вы наполняете объект `f`?

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, `var f = facility;`

Comment: @Igor, Ну так как мы не знаем, что происходит между строками `var f = facility;` и `f.Rooms[i].Knots.push(k);` стоило уточнить у автора, так как полный код есть только у него :-)

Comment: везде все происходит таким же образом. и работает. `f.Rooms.push(r)` но только с конкретно этим не работает. В данном случае естественно  k и r являются временными объектами facility и Room

Comment: показывает действительную длину `f.Rooms.lenght` i находится в нужном диапазоне, но любые обращения к `f.Rooms[i].Knots` - Все та же ошибка

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей. См. [Как создать минимальный, полный, воспроизводимый пример.](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Не написал ничего больше потому что остальное не важно. Каждому полю вышеперечисленных объектов в цикле присваиваются значения полученные при +-/* и т.д. И все работало до этого момента. Только обращение к вложенному массиву который является частью объекта который является массивом в корневом объекте, не работает. ,

Comment: Обсуждение правки этого вопроса на Мете: [Какая информация является несущественной?](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/2475)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Посмотрим на текст ошибки:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Она означает, что была попытка обратиться к свойству `push` у переменной, значение которой равно `undefined`. Посмотрим на код:

```
f.Rooms[i].Knots.push(k);
```

Получается, что

```
f.Rooms[i].Knots == undefined
```

Когда такое может быть? Может ли это быть, если `f.Rooms[i] == undefined`? Не может, поскольку тогда мы бы не смогли обратиться к `Knots`, получив аналогичный `TypeError`. Тогда остаётся последний вариант - у `f.Rooms[i]` свойство `Knots` не было нигде установлено (или явно сброшено в `undefined`). Действительно, если в коде явно не задать значение для какого-либо свойства, то оно считается (ошибки не будет), но его значение будет равно `undefined`.

Вот, собственно, и ответ на вопрос - где-то в коде, который отсутствует в вопросе, в массив `f.Rooms` был положен объект со структурой, отличной от ожидаемой.

Comment: За неимением лучшего. пришлось убрать лишнюю вложенность. перенеся `Knots` в `facility`. Теперь проблемы нет. Но чтоб реализовать то что мне требуется теперь придется выдумывать что-то новое